# show progressbar on sending email

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, progress-bar, c#-2.0

How to show progressbar while sending email using backgroundworker in C#. It should show step by step as we can see while we copy anything to our drive.I am reading excel file to send email.
progressbar1.performstep();

OnClick of Button i am showing Progressbar

```
     private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Visible = true;
        percentageLabel.Visible = true;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();


    }
```

On progress changed event : what to do ??

```
 private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progresBar1.PerformStep();
    }
```

On Do work sendmail : (Note : I need backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress should perform step by step, problem is here i knoww but how to do and what to ? please help here)

```
  private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(98);
        while (!quit)
        {
            // Code to send email here
            sendmail();

        }


    }


  void sendmail()
    {

            string ConStr = "";
            ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Program Files\\CreditControl\\CC\\outstanding.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;\"";
            string query = "SELECT [Agent ID] FROM [Sheet1$] group by [Agent ID]  ";
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConStr);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            conn.Close();

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                if (dt.Rows[i]["Agent ID"].ToString() != "")
                {

                    ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Program Files\\CreditControl\\CC\\agent_mail_master.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;\"";

                    string query2 = "SELECT Mail1,Mail2,Mail3,Mail4,Mail5 FROM [Sheet1$] where [Agent ID] = '" + dt.Rows[i]["Agent ID"].ToString() + "'";
                    OleDbConnection conn2 = new OleDbConnection(ConStr);

                    if (conn2.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        conn2.Open();
                    }
                    OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(query2, conn2);
                    OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd1);
                    System.Data.DataTable dts = new System.Data.DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dts);
                    conn2.Close();
                    if (dts.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        try
                       {

                          SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();
                           MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                           SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("");
                           SmtpServer.Port = 25;
                           SmtpServer.Host = "";
                           mail.From = new MailAddress("");
                         if (dts.Rows[0]["Mail1"].ToString() != "")
                                mail.To.Add(dts.Rows[0]["Mail1"].ToString());
                            if (dts.Rows[0]["Mail2"].ToString() != "")
                                mail.To.Add(dts.Rows[0]["Mail2"].ToString());
                            if (dts.Rows[0]["Mail3"].ToString() != "")
                                mail.To.Add(dts.Rows[0]["Mail3"].ToString());
                            if (dts.Rows[0]["Mail4"].ToString() != "")
                                mail.To.Add(dts.Rows[0]["Mail4"].ToString());
                            if (dts.Rows[0]["Mail5"].ToString() != "")
                                mail.To.Add(dts.Rows[0]["Mail5"].ToString());
                            mail.Subject = "";
                            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

                            ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Program Files\\CreditControl\\CC\\outstanding.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;\"";
                            string query3 = "Select [Date],[Agency Name] ,[Agent ID],[Delay Days],[OD Amount],[Receipt Amount],[Outstanding Amount],Remarks,[Entered By] FROM [Sheet1$] where [Agent ID] ='" + dt.Rows[i]["Agent ID"].ToString() + "'";
                            OleDbConnection conn3 = new OleDbConnection(ConStr);

                            OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(query3, conn3);
                            OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd2);
                            System.Data.DataTable dta = new System.Data.DataTable();
                            oda.Fill(dta);
                            conn3.Close();

                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                           mail.Body = sb.ToString();
                            }
                    }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

                        }

                    }


                }
            }

            quit = true;

    }
```

ON backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted success message :

```
    private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            progressBar1.Visible = false;
            percentageLabel.Text = "";
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Processed successfully");
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to fire the ProgressChangedEvent. something like

```
bgWorker.ReportProgress( PercentageCompleted(...) );
```

also be advised that `progressBar1.Value` expects an Int32 between 0 .. 100 and not a Double between 0 .. 1 (from your code it is not obvious what value you are reporting to your BackgroundWorker)

for ReportStep be sure you set all the required properties. you can find an example on MSDN here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.performstep(v=vs.110).aspx

so in that case you would need to call pbar1.ReportStep() in your ProressChanged-Method instead of setting the Value of pbar1 directly.

EDIT: this is a very basic example from a derived BackgroundWorker how to deal with these events

```
public sealed class MyBackgroundWorker : BackgroundWorker
{
    public MyBackgroundWorker(ProgressBar pBar)
    {
        this.MyProgressBar = pBar;

        this.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        this.WorkerSupportsCancellation = false;

        this.DoWork += MyBackgroundWorker_DoWork;
        this.ProgressChanged += MyBackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged;
        this.RunWorkerCompleted += MyBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    }

    public ProgressBar MyProgressBar { get; private set; }

    void MyBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Finish");
    }
    void MyBackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        SendMail();
    }
    void MyBackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Boolean either = true;          // These are your choices

        if (either)
        {
            // If the ProgressBar has been properly configured regarding
            //
            // this.myProgressBar.Minimum
            //   and
            // this.myProgressBar.Maximum
            //
            // you can simply call

            this.MyProgressBar.PerformStep();
        }
        else
        {
            // If the Progressbar has not been properly configured,
            // you have to assign the value provided by
            // ProgressChangedEvents e like this

            this.MyProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

    }

    private Boolean SendMail()
    {
        // foreach mail in MailsToSend ...

        // Snip - I assume your code for sending mails works correctly

        try
        {
            // Snip
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Snip
        }
        finally
        {
            this.ReportProgress( (100 * cntMailsSent) / cntTotalMailsToSend);
        }

        // quit = true;                 // What do you use this for?
    }
}
```

Comment: kindly see above i had made updation, i know i had manually entered reportprogress.

Comment: ok, I made an update in the comment showing a from BackgroundWorker derived class that updates its progress to a progressbar you provide in the constructor. usually you would only provide the function 'OnProgressChanged' from another object that updates the progressbar located anywhere, but this should work as well